# How do I define a System::Decimal literal for use in an attribute, in C++/CLI?

Tags: configuration, attributes, c++-cli, decimal, literals

As far as I can tell, there is no literal suffix for defining a compile-time constant of type `System::Decimal` (compare to the M suffix in C# -- i.e. `Decimal d = 100.5M`).  Furthermore, the following code is rejected by the compiler:

```
literal System::Decimal myDecimal = 100.5;
```

If I can't define a decimal literal, how then can I initialize an attribute that requires a decimal as one of its fields?  To illustrate, consider the following code:

```
using namespace System;

public ref class MyConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{
public:

    [ConfigurationProperty("Money", DefaultValue = 500.0, IsRequired = false)]
    property Decimal Money { Decimal get(); void set(Decimal value); }
};
```

The current value of 500.0 is invalid as it compiles to type `double`, which is then rejected by the runtime as it doesn't match the type of the property (`Decimal`).

Is it possible to correctly initialize this attribute's default value?

Comment: Impossible even in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DefaultValue = static_cast<Decimal>(500.0)`.

Use of `static_cast` is allowed in constant expressions, as long as it does not require a call to a user-defined conversion function.

---

Failing that, maybe use a global variable which is a constant expression?

```
const Decimal MyConfigElementMoneyDefault = 500.0;

public ref class MyConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{
public:

    [ConfigurationProperty("Money", DefaultValue = MyConfigElementMoneyDefault, IsRequired = false)]
    property Decimal Money { Decimal get(); void set(Decimal value); }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doing so yields error C3101 which states that the attribute value must be a compile-time constant (for /clr:pure, /clr:safe, and /clr).

Comment: @Steve: ok, here's idea #2